# How long does a project take to run in eclipse? **FIXED**

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jpanel

Ok, so I have a project in Computer Science at my school. The project is to create a GUI that calculates how much tax should be put onto a persons income. The problem I am running into is that it takes 3 minutes each time I want to run my program for the program to actually startup. Many people including my teacher say this is not normal. Here is my code:

```
package me.findTax;

/*
*   Notes:
*       Fix the location of all the elements and create the math part of the program
*
*       For some reason, takes eclipse a long time on home & school computers to run this program, not entirely sure why (2+ min)
*
*       If something is not working, try looking a make sure that the change method is called after everytime that the getQuestion method is called
*/

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main { //gives questions (source not included, keylistener included (currently not working), actionlistener included)

static JRadioButton b1;
static JRadioButton b2;
static JFrame frame;
static JPanel panel;
static JLabel L1;
static JLabel L2;
static JTextField tfield;
static ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
static JButton B1;
static double tax;

static boolean married;

static ArrayList<String> poss_Questions = new ArrayList<String>();

private static int q;
// Only need 2 buttons because there is only one prompt (yes or no)

public static void change() {
    if(q == 1) {
        b1.setVisible(false);
        b2.setVisible(false);
        tfield.setVisible(true);
        B1.setVisible(true);
    } else if(q == 2) {
        tfield.setVisible(false);
        B1.setVisible(false);
        L2.setText(Double.toString(tax)); //fix to make output more good
        L2.setVisible(true);
        L1.setLocation(10,20);
    }
}

public static String getQuestion(){
    String question = "";
    if(q == 0){
        question = poss_Questions.get(q);
    } else if(q == 1){
        question = poss_Questions.get(q);
    } else if(q == 2){
        doMath();
        question = poss_Questions.get(q);
    }
    q++;
    L1.setLocation(190, 20);
    if(L1.getText().length() > 16) {
        for(int t = 16; t < L1.getText().length(); t++) {
            L1.setLocation(L1.getX() - 1, L1.getY());
        }
    }
    if(L1.getText().length() < 16) {
        for(int z = 16; z > L1.getText().length(); z++) {
            L1.setLocation(L1.getX() + 1, L1.getY());
        }
    }
    return question;
}

public static void checkAnswer(){
    if(L1.getText().equals(poss_Questions.get(0))){
        if(b1.isSelected()){
            married = true;
        } else if(b2.isSelected()){
            married = false;
        }
    }
}

static int num;
public static void doMath(){
    if(married){
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(tfield.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a whole number above zero without decimal points, commas", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             //may work
        }
        if(num > 0 && num <= 16000) {
            tax = num*0.10; // 10%
        } else if(num > 16000 && num <= 64000) {
            tax = (1600 + (0.15*(num - 16000)));
        } else if(num > 64000) {
            tax = (8800 + (0.25*(num - 64000)));
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value greater than 0, without decimal points, and not in a string format", "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else if(!married){ //if single
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(tfield.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a whole number above zero without decimal points, commas", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        //use else if loops and else (else prints out that there was an error)
        if(num > 0 && num <= 8000) {
            tax = num*0.10; // 10%
        } else if(num > 8000 && num <= 32000) {
            tax = (800 + (0.15*(num - 8000)));
        } else if(num > 32000) {
            tax = (4400 + (0.25*(num - 32000)));
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value greater than 0, without decimal points, and not in a string format", "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    poss_Questions.add("Are you married?");
    poss_Questions.add("How much do you make? ($$ per year)");
    poss_Questions.add("Here is how much tax will be taken away");

    System.err.println("1");

    b1 = new JRadioButton();
    b1.setText("Yes");
    b2 = new JRadioButton();
    b2.setText("No");

    System.err.println("2");

    b1.setVisible(true);
    b2.setVisible(true);
    b1.setBounds(75, 150, 200, 30);
    b2.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 30);

    System.err.println("3");

    bg.add(b1);
    bg.add(b2);

    System.err.println("4");

    B1 = new JButton();
    B1.setText("Submit");
    B1.setVisible(true);
    B1.setLocation(250, 50); 
    B1.setSize(75, 25); 
    B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            checkAnswer();
            L1.setText(getQuestion());
            change();
          } 
    });

    System.err.println("5");

    tfield = new JTextField();
    tfield.setVisible(false);
    tfield.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 20);

    System.err.println("6"); //last output on console until program runs

    L1 = new JLabel();
    L1.setText(getQuestion());
    change();
    L1.setSize(400, 20);
    L1.setLocation(10, 20);

    System.err.println("7");

    L2 = new JLabel();
    L2.setVisible(false);
    L2.setSize(400, 20);
    L2.setLocation(10, 60);
    L2.setText("Something went wrong");

    System.err.println("8");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, L2.getX() + " " + L2.getY());

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setVisible(true);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(480, 270));
    frame.setResizable(false);

    System.err.println("9");

    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(b2);
    panel.add(B1);
    panel.add(L1);
    panel.add(tfield);
    panel.add(L2);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    System.err.println("All");
}
```

}

The main question that arrises in my mind is why it takes so long. The file itself is only about 6kb, which I feel is pretty small and shouldn't take that long to run. I have tried moving the file from a usb to the desktop, tried different computers, **NOTHING WORKS**. Maybe the layout of my code?

I have done some research and non of the forums or tutorial websites have said anything that resembles this problem.

*Thank you in advance*

Comment: Does the three minutes include time to launch Eclipse itself, or just your program within Eclipse. If the latter, what does Eclipse say it is doing -- usually appears in the status bar, bottom right hand corner. Does it say it's rebuilding the workspace or some such? What else is in your workspace?

Comment: @PeterSwords no, that is the time from when I hit the green 'run' button. There is nothing else in my workspace either. Also, there are no indications from eclipse as to why it is taking such a long period of time. (it doesnt give any status bars, doesnt say rebuilding workspace)

Comment: "Projects" don't have a runtime; running one just means running your code, however long that takes. Launching a project (that is, starting your code running) is normally instantaneous. Open the Progress tab and see if there's anything showing.

Comment: @chrylis when I open the progress tab, it says "No operations to display at this time." Still, after about 3 minutes passes, the program will show

Comment: Time to start debugging. The first step is to add `System.err.println("1");` after your first `main` paragraph, `"2"` after the next one, and so on, so you can see on the console where the program is hanging (or if you never even see the `1` in the first place). There are more complicated ways to debug a problem like this, but that's a good simple first strategy.

(By the way, as a side note, `JOptionPane` provides a yes/no dialog ready to go.)

Comment: @chrylis okay, so that did give me some information. The error occurs where L1 is set. I updated the code and put the lines that I added. The last thing that outputs in the console is "6". And I used the radio buttons on purpose as that is what my teacher preferred

Comment: Your `getQuestion` method is doing several things that aren't just getting a question. I strongly recommend that you look at replacing the hand-rolled dialog box with `JOptionPane` if possible. If not, you'll need to put a breakpoint on `L1.setText` (double-click the left margin of the editor, and you'll see a blue dot) and then launch the program from Debug.

Comment: there is an endless loop(overflows  until condition met): "for (int z = 16; z > L1.getText().length(); z++) " I guess it should be z-- or something.

Comment: @kai - not quite an "endless loop" - it *eventually* terminates.  But yes, that's the problem

Comment: That infinite loop is also detected by a static code analysis tool such as SonarLint. I would actually recommend programming newcomers to make use of such tools, since they can be quite educational and notify you about logical mistakes that are otherwise syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program runs into an "endless" loop.
If you look in getQuestion() in the last loop:

```
if (L1.getText().length() < 16) {
   for (int z = 16; z > L1.getText().length(); z++) {
            L1.setLocation(L1.getX() + 1, L1.getY());
   }
```

This loop starts with 16 when L1.getText().length() < 16 hence z > L1.getText().length() is true by definition.

When z is incremented with every loop z gets even bigger and will even more meet the condition. So it is incremented endlessly. Well not endlessly - when it gets big enough it will overflow and become negative. This is when it stops.

In the below code I replaced the increment with an decrement of z. While I do not know if it is logically what you  want - it removes the endless loop and the program comes up way faster. By that showing that this error is causing your problems:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main { //gives questions (source not included, keylistener included (currently not working), actionlistener included)

    static JRadioButton b1;
    static JRadioButton b2;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel;
    static JLabel L1;
    static JLabel L2;
    static JTextField tfield;
    static ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    static JButton B1;
    static double tax;

    static boolean married;

    static ArrayList<String> poss_Questions = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static int q=0;
// Only need 2 buttons because there is only one prompt (yes or no)

    public static String getQuestion() {
        String question = "";
        if (q == 0) {
            question = poss_Questions.get(q);
        } else if (q == 1) {
            question = poss_Questions.get(q);
            b1.setVisible(false);
            b2.setVisible(false);
            tfield.setVisible(true);
            B1.setVisible(true);
        } else if (q == 2) {
            doMath();
            question = poss_Questions.get(q);
            tfield.setVisible(false);
            B1.setVisible(false);
            L2.setText(Double.toString(tax)); //fix to make output more good
            L2.setVisible(true);
        }
        q++;
        L1.setLocation(190, 20);
        if (L1.getText().length() > 16) {
            for (int t = 16; t < L1.getText().length(); t++) {
                L1.setLocation(L1.getX() - 1, L1.getY());
            }
        }
        if (L1.getText().length() < 16) {
            for (int z = 16; z > L1.getText().length(); z--) {
                L1.setLocation(L1.getX() + 1, L1.getY());
            }
        }
        return question;
    }

    public static void checkAnswer() {
        if (L1.getText().equals(poss_Questions.get(0))) {
            if (b1.isSelected()) {
                married = true;
            } else if (b2.isSelected()) {
                married = false;
            }
        }
    }

    static int num;

    public static void doMath() {
        if (married) {
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(tfield.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a whole number above zero without decimal points, commas", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                //may work
            }
            if (num > 0 && num <= 16000) {
                tax = num * 0.10; // 10%
            } else if (num > 16000 && num <= 64000) {
                tax = (1600 + (0.15 * (num - 16000)));
            } else if (num > 64000) {
                tax = (8800 + (0.25 * (num - 64000)));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value greater than 0, without decimal points, and not in a string format", "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else if (!married) { //if single
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(tfield.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a whole number above zero without decimal points, commas", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            //use else if loops and else (else prints out that there was an error)
            if (num > 0 && num <= 8000) {
                tax = num * 0.10; // 10%
            } else if (num > 8000 && num <= 32000) {
                tax = (800 + (0.15 * (num - 8000)));
            } else if (num > 32000) {
                tax = (4400 + (0.25 * (num - 32000)));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value greater than 0, without decimal points, and not in a string format", "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        poss_Questions.add("Are you married?");
        poss_Questions.add("How much do you make? ($$ per year)");
        poss_Questions.add("Here is how much tax will be taken away");

        b1 = new JRadioButton();
        b1.setText("Yes");
        b2 = new JRadioButton();
        b2.setText("No");

        b1.setVisible(true);
        b2.setVisible(true);
        b1.setBounds(75, 150, 200, 30);
        b2.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 30);

        bg.add(b1);
        bg.add(b2);

        B1 = new JButton();
        B1.setText("Submit");
        B1.setVisible(true);
        B1.setLocation(340, 50);
        B1.setSize(75, 25);
        B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                checkAnswer();
                L1.setText(getQuestion());
            }
        });

        tfield = new JTextField();
        tfield.setVisible(false);
        tfield.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 20);

        L1 = new JLabel();
        L1.setText(getQuestion());
        L1.setSize(400, 20);
        L1.setLocation(10, 20);

        L2 = new JLabel();
        L2.setVisible(false);
        L2.setSize(400, 20);
        L2.setLocation(10, 60);
        L2.setText("Something went wrong");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, L2.getX() + " " + L2.getY());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setVisible(true);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(480, 270));
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(B1);
        panel.add(L1);
        panel.add(tfield);
        panel.add(L2);

        panel.setLayout(null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually keyed in your program.

Q: Do Eclipse programs take three minutes or longer to launch?

A: No, not unless you've got a VERRRY slow computer, or you've exceeded RAM and you're hitting swap.

Q: Does *your* program take up to three minutes before you "see something"?

A: Yes.

SUGGESTION:

Set a breakpoint in "main()", and hit "F6" to single step a line at a time (and/or "F5" to step into functions you want to examine).

Hint: Your program should launch promptly, and things will go quickly ... until you hit "getQuestion()" ;)

STRONG SUGGESTION:

An essential part of "programming" is to learn how to troubleshoot and debug.  This is an excellent chance to familiarize yourself with how to use the Eclipse debugger to single-step through your code.